# Computer Locking Up While Using PySerial

Tags: arduino, pyserial

While using this code if the functions are ran too often/for too long the entire computer will lock up and the program will close

```
import serial

# Define the serial port and baud rate
ser = serial.Serial(port = 'COM8', baudrate = 115200)  # Replace 'COM3' with the appropriate port name
# time.sleep(2)  # Allow some time for the serial connection to be established
ser.reset_input_buffer()
ser.reset_output_buffer()

x,y = 10,10
def move_mouse(x, y):
    ser.write(f"M{x} {y}\n".encode())
    ser.flush()

def send_mouse_click():
    ser.write("C".encode())
    ser.flush()
```

I run the script (slightly different but condensed for readability) which runs the functions over and over and after a few seconds it will lock up the computer and crash the program.

Comment: The problem is most likely with the way you call it over and over.  Are you repeatedly creating that Serial object and not closing it?

Comment: I'm opening the 
ser = serial.Serial(port = 'COM8', baudrate = 115200) 
sending a bunch of movements
def move_mouse(x, y):
    ser.write(f"M{x} {y}\n".encode())
    ser.flush()
and it crashes during those movement inputs

Comment: That's a description of some code.  I can't tell you why it doesn't work from a description.   There are literally infinite number of mistakes you may have made.  If you're not going to post your code then you should just delete the question.  It can't be answered without seeing that.